# How to limit queries in JPA and Informix?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, informix

When I'm on the first page of my result list, here's the generated query:

```
select first 10 books0_.id as id100_...
```

And everything works fine. However, on the second page I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: ResultSet Type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.
```

The code for the listing is here:

```
// calculating paging offset
int perPage = Integer.parseInt(Constants.RESULTS_PER_PAGE);
int firstResult = (page == null) ? 0 : (page - 1) * perPage;

CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Books> criteria = builder.createQuery(Books.class);

Root<Books> entityRoot = criteria.from(Books.class);
criteria.select(entityRoot);

// constructing list of parameters
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
...

// add the list of parameters
criteria.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));

//execute query and paginate results
TypedQuery<Books> listQuery = em.createQuery(criteria);
listQuery.setFirstResult(firstResult);
listQuery.setMaxResults(perPage);

return listQuery.getResultList();
```

And the generated query for the second query is:

```
select first 20 books0_.id as id100_...
```

when it should be `skip 10 first 10`. How can I use the JPA paging methods now?

I'm using `JBoss 7.1`, `Spring 3.2`, `Hibernate 4.0.1` and `Informix 11.70`.

Comment: what is the initial value of page? Where do you initialize/set this value?

Comment: Its `page=0` the first time. The RESULTS_PER_PAGE is 10. There is nothing wrong with the calculating of the pages, it works when I use native queries with `SKIP` and `FIRST`.

Comment: You can look at following example to achieve same using criteria builder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144487/jpa-paging-with-numbers-and-next-previous

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Hibernate team is not updating dialect for Informix DBMS for quite some time, so InformixDialect in hibernate distribution doesn't support SKIP feature. 
Hibernate JIRA is having issue for updating InformixDialect [HHH-5414](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5414) with patch supplied (opened for more than three years).

You could try to replace InformixDialect class with one from [IIUG site](http://www.iiug.org/opensource/).
Simply put that file in your project in respectful package directory and try it out.